# elasticsearch must restart master for new node joining in zen discovery

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch cluster of version 1.5.2
There is one master node and one data node in the cluster.
When I add a new data node into the cluster(with the same **cluster name**) with the name **node.name : "Node2"**, the new node can't join in the cluster **with no logs** indicating what happens.
My main conifg file is as below:
**master node config:**

```
cluster.name: cluster1
node.name: "Master"
node.master: true
node.data: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.retries: 6
discovery.zen.ping.interval: 30s
```

**data node config of node1:**

```
cluster.name: cluster1
node.name: "Node1"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.retries: 6
discovery.zen.ping.interval: 30s
```

**data node config of node2:**

```
cluster.name: cluster1
node.name: "Node2"
node.master: false
node.data: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.retries: 6
discovery.zen.ping.interval: 30s
```

When I restart the master node, the new node successfully join in the cluster.
Does anyone know how to join new nodes into the cluster without restarting the master??

Comment: You have the same node name for both node1 and node2: `node.name: "Node1"`

Comment: @Stefan  I typed the wrong node name and I have changed it to "Node2". It still failed to join the cluster

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [unicast](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#unicast), you need to add:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts = [...]
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled = False
```

If you're using multicast, you need to set the [appropriate multicast settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#multicast) (for [external multicast](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#_external_multicast)).

If you're using AWS, I suggest looking at the [elasticsearch-cloud-aws](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-cloud-aws) plugin.

PS: In the current configuration, you have no data nodes.

Comment: I use multicast and I think I use the right setting. The problem seems that the master can't discover the new node until I restart the master.

Comment: @tottishi05 You're going to have to give more information.  What's the output from the nodes that are unable to find the master?

Comment: @tottishi05 Also, are you doing anything else during the restart?  As in, is this part of a build process and other operations are triggered?  Or are you simply killing the process and relaunching the elasticsearch client?

Comment: Neither the master nor the new node recorded any logs about discovering each other in the failed instance. I just type "kill -2 pid" to kill the master and restart it, then it can discover the new node and add it into the cluster